# How to blend 2 textures into a third specific color in opengl es

Tags: android, opengl-es-1.1

I am trying to do a little bit of a design on a little program for android.
I am using OpenGL ES1 for this. I am drawing 2 quads on the screen. When the quads intersects the must show a third color.

Like this:

http://www.marlonbodhi.com/mix.jpg

So I am trying to mix these 2 textures into a third color when they intersect. Is there somewhere I can setup Opengl to do that?

Comment: Take a look at the stencil buffer.  It can do this efficiently.

Comment: ClayMontgomery : Sorry for the long waiting on replying.. Exams.. Many thanks for your answer! It does exactly what I needed! +1